# Bash - Run 'chage' Command Against Each User Account

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, user-management, user-accounts

I have to audit the users accounts on our linux servers in each environment so I want to script checking whether each account is expired or not. I have a **for loop** that's pulling user accounts listed in /etc/passwd and stores them in an **array**.

```
#!/bin/bash
users = $(awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd)
uservar=($users)

for value in "${uservar[0]}"
do chage -l $value
done
```

Ideally the script would **display a username first** then on a new line it would show the **account expiration date and other info for that user account**. The process would repeat for each account. At the moment its just displaying the account expiration and dates for all user accounts without the username so I can't tell the accounts apart. Everything is also stacked on top of each other so its difficult to read. Ideally the output would look like this:

```
userA
Last Password Change:    1/2/34
Password Expires:        1/2/34
Password Inactive:       1/2/34
.....

userB
Last Password Change:    1/2/34
Password Expires:        1/2/34
Password Inactive:       1/2/34
.....
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestions on this.

Comment: Just my short google skills: https://www.2daygeek.com/linux-check-user-password-expiration-date - i think this can be extened to your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question:

```
#!/bin/bash
users=$(awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd)

for value in $users
do 
      echo $value
      chage -l $value
      echo "....."
      echo ""
 done
```

should generate output in the form of

```
userA
Last Password Change:    1/2/34
Password Expires:        1/2/34
Password Inactive:       1/2/34
.....

userB
Last Password Change:    1/2/34
Password Expires:        1/2/34
Password Inactive:       1/2/34
.....
```

---

Note that the source of the information `chage` displays is encoded in the fields of the [`/etc/shadow`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) file (expressed as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970) .
Parsing that file directly might be significantly more efficient than using `chage` and/or other tools that convert those fields to human readable output and parsing that.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Is it possible to add passwd --status <user> to a separate line? When I try to run it similar to the chage -l cmd it complains about a syntax error. I'm assuming it has to do with --status?

Comment: Disregard, I realized I can use 'passwd -S' which accomplishes the same thing. Thanks again for the help!